# To-do app, as one monster function and as several smaller functions

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, comparative-review, to-do-list

I am learning to code by making a todo app in pure javascript. My first attempt can be seen [here](http://conquerjs.com/todo).

It's all cosmetic, meaning it stores no information, generates no objects or arrays, though it was sure fun to learn how to manipulate DOM elements in pure JavaScript and building my first "program"!

I am rebuilding it in a more OOP manner. In this [first jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv6ohr9b/):

```
when(toDo, "keypress", function(event){
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    pushArray();
    toDo.value = "";
  }
});

function pushArray(){
  var nt = new Task(toDo.value, "No note yet");
  fruits.push(nt);
  var task = document.createElement("div");
  task.setAttribute("class", "taskitem");
  task.innerHTML = nt.Name;
  var t = document.createElement("input");
  t.setAttribute("class", "tasknote");
  task.appendChild(t);
  when(t, "keypress", function(event){
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    nt.Note = t.value;
    this.parentNode.innerHTML = nt.Name + " " + nt.Note;
    t.value = "";
  }
});

  result.appendChild(task);
  console.log(fruits);
}
```

Hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> fires a function that does everything. creates a new task object, pushes it to the array, displays the task and appends a note that can be updated anytime, for example -  task:get milk note:almond milk. However I eventually want to rebuild this app again using local storage, and again with ajax and JSON. I'm thinking I'm going to have a hard time injecting that functionality into this single function without breaking it. So I did it again and broke the steps down into several smaller functions that 'plug' into each other:  https://jsfiddle.net/8wm0r345/

```
  function Task(name, note) {
  this.Note = note;
  this.Name = name;
  this.completed = false;
}

function pushArray() {
  var nt = new Task(toDo.value, "No note yet");
  taskArray.push(nt);
  displayArray(result, nt.Name);
  appendNote(result, nt);
}

function displayArray(x, obj) {
  var task = make("div", "class", "taskitem", obj);
  x.appendChild(task);
}

function appendNote(el, obj) {
  var t = make("input", "class", "tasknote");
  el.appendChild(t);
  when(t, "keypress", submitNote.bind(null, obj, t));
}

function submitNote(newTask, theInput) {
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    newTask.Note = theInput.value;
    var n = make("div", "class", "hasNote", newTask.Note);
    var t = theInput;
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(n, t.nextSibling);
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
    when(n, "dblclick", function() {
      n.parentNode.insertBefore(t, n.nextSibling);
      n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
    });
  }
}
```

My question is: What is the recommended approach to building a small program like this? And are there any alarming issues in either code presented here?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As a courtesy, please [declare your cross-posts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34754483/1157100).

Comment: I would urge you to use descriptive names for your variables instead of "n", "t", etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic, you need to include *all* of your code, and not leave things out like `fruits`.

Comment: @Quill While it would be better if the question contained a full runnable example, simply posting an excerpt of the code to be reviewed does not make it off-topic, especially when a runnable example is available as a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `nt` and `t` as variable names. If you were using them in a small limited context then it wouldn't be much of an issue, but repeatedly using them across multiple lines is going to get confusing. What's wrong with `newTask` and `task`?

In the case of `var nt = new Task(toDo.value, "No note yet");` it's pretty clear what `nt` is there, but I'm not even sure if `t` is a task, or a `note` on the task, or user `input`. A clear name makes code more readable, and leaves people guessing at your intentions less.

`x` in `displayArray` is even worse. Though it *is* a limited context, you make it seem as though it accepts arbitrary input (`x` doesn't specify anything) when it clearly needs something that can have a child appended.

That said I personally like the split up functions a lot more. With individual functions, it's easier to read them and see what the functions do. It's easy for steps to get lost in a big megafunction, but when each step is it's own function you can make everything more explanatory.

However the readability principle applies again. I'm not very familiar with JS, so maybe `displayArray` makes sense for that, but to me I can't see why a `display` function is appending something to the HTML. Surely it should be another `append` function?